# How to add text inside a Toggle Switch Component in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How can I add text inside a Switch component in ReactJS? I am trying to add `EN` and `PT` text inside the Switch Component.

I'm not using any lib, I built the component with only css, because I needed it to have this specific customization, so I found it easier to do with css.

I put my project into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-switch-6s4qx?file=/src/index.js)

[image]

```js
import React from "react";
import "./switch.css";

const Switch = ({ isOn, handleToggle, onColor }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        checked={isOn}
        onChange={handleToggle}
        className="react-switch-checkbox"
        id={`react-switch-new`}
        type="checkbox"
      />
      <label
        style={{ background: isOn && onColor }}
        className="react-switch-label"
        htmlFor={`react-switch-new`}
      >
        <span className={`react-switch-button`} />
      </label>
    </>
  );
};

export default Switch;
```

```css
.react-switch-checkbox {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.react-switch-label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.react-switch-label .react-switch-button {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  background: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.29);
}

.react-switch-checkbox:checked + .react-switch-label .react-switch-button {
  left: calc(100% - 2px);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.react-switch-label:active .react-switch-button {
  width: 60px;
}
```

Thank you very much for any help!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [my fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-switch-forked-vv3dp) of your sandbox.
First of all, I moved the `<input>` into the `<label>` so it doesn't require the `id`/`htmlFor` structure that would break due to duplicate id's once you use multiple switches.

The text `span`s are now in their own `div` inside the `label`. They each have 50% width, are aligned to the left and right edges respectively and use flexbox to center their contents.

Depending on the width of the white area in either state of the checkbox, you might want to change the spans' width to center the text correctly. Also, the label texts can be moved to a property for reusability.